# Getting 500 Internal issue during ajax response

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am struggling with this code. I am unable to send a response with ajax.
Ajax script is here.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#selectSize').change(function () {
                var idSize = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                        type: "get",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: 'getproductprice',
                        data: {
                                idSize: idSize
                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                                console.log("working");
                        },
                        error: function () {
                                console.log("error");
                        }
                });
        });
});
```

Here is the Blade markup

```
<select name="size" id="selectSize" style="width:150px;">
    <option value="">Select Size</option>
    @foreach($productDetails->attributes as $size)
        <option value="{{$productDetails->id}}-{{$size->size}}">{{$size->size}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

And here is the controller code

```php
public function getProductPrice(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $proArr = explode("-", $data['idsize']);
    $proAttr = ProductsAttribute::where(['product_id' => $proArr[0], 'size' => $proArr[1]])->first();
    $getCurrencyRates = Product::getCurrencyRates($proAttr->price);
    echo $proAttr->price . "-" . $getCurrencyRates['USD_Rate'] . "-" . $getCurrencyRates['GBP_Rate'] . "-" . $getCurrencyRates['EUR_Rate'];
    echo "#";
    echo $proAttr->stock;
}
```

I do not know, What I am doing wrong .when I select option value.
error will come like.

> "Trying to get property 'image' of non-object (View: 
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wrost\resources\views\shop\product-details.blade.php)"

Comment: Change - `$proArr = explode("-",$data['idsize']);`  to `$proArr = explode("-",$data['idSize']);`.On the other hand please check is exist `image` in your database and application folder or not.

Comment: It may cause, probably `$proAttr` has `image` field and value but the image does not exist in your application.

Comment: Rashaed Hashan@All thing working on  other place

Comment: What do you mean in other place? In existing application with other controller, method or another new applicatoin?

Comment: @in a different application with same method and same ajax  call

Comment: Rashed hasen@ ajax return this url@ 
 http://localhost/wrost/public/product/getproductprice?idSize=3-medioum

Comment: okay, then it may be the application cache. Would you please run `php artisan cache:clear`,  `php artisan route:cache`,  `php artisan view:clear` from terminal inside your application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200476/discussion-between-sanjay-yadav-and-rashed-hasan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ajax` should be -

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'getproductprice',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {idSize: idSize},
            beforeSend: function (request) {
                return request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr('content'));
            },
            success: function (response) {
               console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                alert("Something Went Wrong, Please check again");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks@ lot @ This is a perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you add `meta tag` for `csrf` in your head

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

At last you need to add `header` object in your ajax object

```
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}
```

it will be like this

```
$.ajax({
   type: "get",
   dataType : 'json',
   headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
   },
   url:'getproductprice', 
   data: {idSize: idSize},
   success:function(response){
   console.log("working");
  },
  error:function(){
   console.log("error");
  }
});
```

Comment: @after This I have same issue. I thin problem with url

Comment: @sanjayyadav yah you true it's a typo error `csrf_token()` i write it wrong try again

Comment: i think this not allowed here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200471/discussion-between-sanjay-yadav-and-joseph).